# Main range change value here child range -css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three range first range it Main , and another it child .. when i change main range i want automatically change another range

```html
Main:<input type="range" name="range" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="200" 0 style="width:100%;" /> <br> <BR>
  Child range:<br>
<input type="range" name="range" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="200" 0/><input type="range" name="range" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="200" />
<h3>when i change Main range i want change child range with Main
</h3>
```

Comment: What is the relationship between them?

Comment: The main change value here child .. i Search relationship between them !! @AdamAzad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic example

```js
window.onload = function(){
  
  var rangeMain = document.getElementById('main'),
      rangeChild1 = document.getElementById('child1'),
      rangeChild2 = document.getElementById('child2');
  rangeMain.onchange = function(){
      rangeChild1.value = this.value;
      rangeChild2.value = this.value;
  }
  
}
```

```html
Main:<input id="main" type="range" name="range" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="200" 0 style="width:100%;" /> <br> <BR>
  Child range:<br>
   <input id="child1" type="range" name="range" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="200" 0/>
   <input id="child2" type="range" name="range" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="200" />
<h3>when i change Main range i want change child range with Main
</h3>
```

If you want live feedback as the range changes without waiting for mouse release, you could listen `oninput`

```js
var rangeMain = document.getElementById('main'),
    rangeChild1 = document.getElementById('child1'),
    rangeChild2 = document.getElementById('child2');
rangeMain.onchange = function(){
    rangeChild1.value = this.value;
    rangeChild2.value = this.value;
}
rangeMain.oninput = function(){
    rangeChild1.value = this.value;
    rangeChild2.value = this.value;
}
```

```html
Main:<input id="main" type="range" name="range" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="200" 0 style="width:100%;" /> <br> <BR>
  Child range:<br>
   <input id="child1" type="range" name="range" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="200" 0/>
   <input id="child2" type="range" name="range" step="1" value="0" min="0" max="200" />
<h3>when i change Main range i want change child range with Main
</h3>
```

Comment: Excellent That's what I want ... but can you change the other range too .. for accept  your answr

Comment: Never mind, something was wrong with my browser, but when I reloaded my page it worked, sorry @AdamAzad.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah, no problems :)

Comment: that worked but when i put the javascrip in head no worked

Comment: @JackKing, you need to wrap the code into `window.onload = function(){
/* code from answer */ }`

Comment: I do not understand :D @AdamAzad

Comment: I updated the first snippet as an example, you can use it the same way in the second snippet.